# Does an ellipse have sine and cosine?

Tags: trigonometry, elliptic-curves

As the title says: what is, if any, the sine and cosine of an ellipse?

Comment: You're going to have to try harder to ask your question in a way that makes sense. Sine and cosine are functions that take _angles_ as input.

Comment: Related? (Duplicate?): ["Are there parabolic and elliptical functions analogous to the circular and hyperbolic functions sin(h),cos(h), and tan(h)?"](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/59991/409)

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You must have something in mind, but you need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An ellipse is a curve,
so the concept of 
taking a sin or cos
of it
doesn't make much sense.

However,
an ellipse
with semi-major axis $a$
and semi-minor axis $b$
 can be *described*
by the equations
$x = a \cos(t), y=b\sin(t)$
as $t$ goes from $0$
to $2\pi$.

Comment: You can talk about the sine or cosine of the set of x or y values, but you have to be careful. That is not standard terminology, so you have to made clear what you mean.